# ReactNative FlatList nested inside FlatList

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I want to do something like this:

[image: img1]

If you need more information, please let me know! Hope someone can help me!

```
    const DATA=[[1,name1,...],[2,name2,...]...];// Data like [[...],[...],...]
    
    <FlatList
      data={DATA}  
      keyExtractor={(outterItem)=>outterItem.key}
      renderItem={({outterItem})=>(                                                                          
      <View>
        <FlatList
          horizontal={true}
          data={outterItem}
          keyExtractor={(innerItem)=>innerItem.key}
          renderItem={({InnerItem})=>(  
            <View style={styles.box}>
              <Text style={styles.Text}>{InnerItem}</Text>
            </View>
          )}   
        />
      </View>
    />
```

Comment: What exactly is not working in your current code?

Comment: <Text>{InnerItem}</Text>didn't work. I changed <Text style={styles.Text}>{InnerItem}</Text> to <Text style={styles.Text}>test</Text>,and also nothing appear. I don't know why .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destructuring the `item` parameter of the `renderItem` function of `FlatList`. You cannot rename it to `innerItem` or `outerItem`. The name must be `item` for both. Thre will be no conflict since the `item` parameter will be inside the local scope.

Here is a working version with a dummy data array.

```js
export default function App() {
  const DATA=[[1,2,3],[2, 3, 4 ,5]];
  return (
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}  
    keyExtractor={(item, index)=>index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item})=>(                                                                          
    <View>
        <FlatList
              horizontal={true}
              data={item}
              keyExtractor={(item, index)=> index.toString()}
              renderItem={({item})=> (  
                  <View style={styles.box}>
                      <Text style={styles.Text}>{item}</Text>
                   </View>
              )}   
         />
    </View>)} 
  />)
}
```

Comment: It work !thank you very much,but I have another question ,**It appear at first time I enter the component,but after render everything disappear**,I guess it is cause by my DATA Source. `const Source=useSelector(source);const [DATA,setData]=useState([ ]);
        
        useEffect(()=>
        {
            Source.map((item)=>{
                DATA.push([item.Number,item.Name]);
                 
            });
          
        },[]);`

Comment: Try setting the state via the `setData` function. `setData(Source.map((item) => { return [item.Number, item.Name]}))`.

Comment: It work!!!!! It cost me almost two day,really thank!!!

Comment: But can you tell me why I need to use `setData` rather than`DATA.push([item.Number,item.Name])`

Comment: You cannot alter the state directly, you need to use its setter function in order to trigger a state change. This is just how the react library works.