# React Native nested array rendering in a View

Tags: arrays, react-native, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling to get my multi-dimensional array to render in my React Native app (sidenote: using Expo to simulate on my phone).

I am looking to get it to iterate and display the `title` value of all the items in the multi-array.

I have tried following the following link on logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518868/3658694, but I'm still struggling to render the multi-array data (it's probably a small issue).

See my `Flatlist` component below, where I'm struggling on logic.

**The data**

```
const DATAARRAY = [
{
  sdata: [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'One',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Two',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Three',
    },
    {
      id: 'bd7acwea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'Four',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac62afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Five',
    },
    {
      id: '58692a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Six',
    },
  ]
}
];
```

**'Item' component** (a display block to render the title text)

```
//Item component
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

**Flatlist** (App component)

```
//Flatlist rendered
< FlatList style={styles.flatList}
  data={DATAARRAY}
  keyExtractor={item => 'sdata'}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    < FlatList
      data={item}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
    />
  )}
/>
```

I've stripped out all other coding for clearer illustration here.

*(After I figure this out, I am fairly confident on manipulating the multi-array structure from a database query result instead, in the same way, to replace the above test data array)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sdata` property is the nested array, so nested `FlatList` should use that as data.

```
<FlatList
  data={DATAARRAY}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <FlatList
      data={item.sdata}
...
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... a knew it was a simple thing I was overlooking (I'm relatively new and learning React's syntax and prop usage).